# AWS Glue Python ETL: logger messages appear in the error cloudwatch stream

Tags: python, logging, etl, aws-glue

I'm writing a Glue ETL, and I'm trying to log using Python default's `logger`.

The problem is that all the log messages I'm printing using the logger appear in the error stream of the job.

If I print directly to stdout (using `print`), I see the printed messages in the regular cloudwatch log stream.

I tried to redirect my logger to stdout, but I still got the same result: messages appear in error stream.

Does anyone know how I can use logger, and still see my messages in the log cloudwatch stream? (and not in the error cloudwatch stream)

This is the code sample I'm using to test:

```
import logging
import sys

MSG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s: %(message)s'
DATETIME_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
logging.basicConfig(format=MSG_FORMAT, datefmt=DATETIME_FORMAT, stream=sys.stdout)
logger = logging.getLogger()

logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logger.info("Test log message. This appear on the job error cloudwatch stream")

print("This is a print. This appear on the job log cloudwatch stream")
```

Comment: print() statements showed on /aws-glue/jobs/output in my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up adding

```
logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout))
```

to my logger definition. 
That resolved the problem